Under what conditions will a circuit violate conservation of charge and/or conservation of energy?
Consider the following circuit diagram containing two capacitors and an inductor:

Suppose that $C_1$ is initially charged to some voltage $V_i$ and that $S_1$ is closed at $t=0$. If the switches are then closed and opened with perfect timing, the maximum current flowing through $L$ can be transferred into $C_2$, charging it up to some voltage $V_f$
(and leaving $C_1$ completely uncharged).
In general in circuits, two conservation rules apply: Conservation of Charge and Conservation of Energy. In the above circuit, conservation of charge would imply that
$$
C_1 V_i = C_2 V_f
$$
meaning that
$$
V_f = V_i \frac{C_1}{C_2}
$$
However, Conservation of Energy implies that
$$
\frac{1}{2} C_1 V_i^2 = \frac{1}{2} C_2 V_f^2
$$
meaning that
$$
V_f = V_i \sqrt{\frac{C_1}{C_2}}
$$
These two conservation rules clearly can't apply simultaneously.
Through some careful calculus and algebra, it can be shown that Conservation of Charge is violated but Conservation of Energy holds. In fact, depending on the relative capacitances, the final amount of charge could be greater or less than the initial amount of charge; it stays the same only when $C_1=C_2$.
However, in other, similar circuits Conservation of Charge holds but Conservation of Energy is violated -- such as when a charged capacitor is connected to another uncharged capacitor in a closed loop, as in the following diagram:

QUESTION: When is charge (or energy) conserved in a circuit and when is it not conserved? Where does the charge (or energy) go when it is lost to the circuit?

I can’t get passed the paragraph beginning with “Suppose that….”. The timing of the switch S2 with respect to S1 is unclear

@BobD Well, it's a very common undergraduate homework question to show that the maximum current occurs at one-fourth the period of oscillation in an LC circuit. At that moment in time, the capacitor is completely uncharged, so if the switches are simultaneously opened and closed (respectively), the current will flow into the second, newly formed LC circuit.

Note that total charge in the entire circuit is conserved (zero), but the sum of the charge levels on the capacitors need not be.

Kirchoff’s current law (KCL) implements the conservation of charge in a circuit. Kirchoff’s voltage law (KVL) implements the conservation of energy in a circuit. See Boundless Physics, various online tutorials, or standard print textbooks (e.g. Serway, 3rd ed, p 765, 772). Both KVL and KCL always hold in a circuit, or more explicitly, they both always hold in any device that can be accurately described using circuit theory.
In your analysis, the conservation of charge law that you state is incorrect. Conservation of charge actually comes through KCL. Recall that the charge on a capacitor is not a net charge, it is a charge separation. The conservation of charge does not imply that the separation of charge is constant.
Regarding the other circuit and conservation of energy. As I said above, both energy and charge are conserved in any device that can be accurately described using circuit theory. This is any device that meets the three assumptions of circuit theory:

No magnetic flux between components
No changing net charge on any component
The time scales of interest are large compared to the time it takes for EM waves to propagate across the circuit.

The two capacitor circuit has a 0 time constant, so it violates that third requirement regardless of the size of the circuit. This can be resolved by adding a resistance such that $RC \gg d/c$. Then the usual rules of circuit theory apply, including KVL, and the energy goes into the resistor.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
